# Liquid layout: avoid change in body width due to vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have implemented liquid layout for my website. I have set width of body tag to 100%.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        some content
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

For some pages vertical scrollbar is displayed. Because of which body tag width reduces by 16px. I need to set body width in such a way that display of scrollbar doesn't affect it.
I have tried following but it didn't work with FF9. :

> > ```
> >  body{
> >     width: -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
> > }
> > ```

Can any body suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to work around this is to make sure scroll bars are always present. You can then style your pages with confidence that they're not going to shift left and right.

```
html,body
{
 height:101%;
}
```

You can also do:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

(I don't think the overflow method works with Opera though)

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the issue but idea of having scroll bar even if there is no need to scroll doesn't sound good to me. Is there any other way except JS?

Comment: I don't know of another way off the top of my head however I do prefer to always have the scroll bars, especially if some pages do extend and some don't. I pefer to have scroll bars rather than a shifting page.

Comment: Ok :) Another way I can think of is to set the width using JS. Let's see if somebody can suggest any way to solve this issue.

Comment: I think `min-height` is better than forcing `height` to a given percentage.

Answer (score 0):

This probably wasn't possible possible at the time that this question was asked, but these days you can do this:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

The only potential downside is that the rightmost 16px will be covered by the scrollbar when it appears, but you might actually want this if your project fits any of these conditions:

- You really don't want your pages to overflow vertically except when there is enough content to fill the space, or you don't like the look of a seemingly unnecessary scrollbar
- The right-most 16 pixels cover nothing important, and you have the same background image on each page that needs to scale with the viewport width, and look identical on all pages

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use calc so or so. It is not implemented in Chrome,

If you have your width set to 100% your container don't gets affected by the vertical scrollbar anyways. It's at every time 100% width. With or without scrollbar it fills at everytime 100% of the viewport.

Comment: I have compared body width's of pages having scroll bar with of those not having scrollbars. There is exact difference of 16px. I tested using FF9 and Chrome 17.

Comment: yes, there is that difference, but your page is still shown in 100% of the seeable viewport(viewportwidth - scrollbar width). If you have your complete page scaled right, there will be no problem if a scrollbar is shown or not. All sizes will then match the seeable viewport. It would be the same as if I resize the width of my browser a bit.

Comment: yes, I understand what you are saying. Now the issue is, some pages have vertical scrollbar displayed while some do not have it. So if user switches between pages rapidly, it looks as if width of site layout is changing slightly.(because of space taken by scrollbar) I am trying to fix this issue.